# When to use scene or panel

Tags: unity-game-engine, scene

I just have a question and I don't know exactly what to type on google.

I am making a game which is always instantiating scenes now on my login process I am trying to login wrong account so there should be something that needs to pop up like an error message

[image]

Now my question is . Is there going to be a problem when I build this up because there's a tons of them or it is just normal?

But basically when i try to input the correct id and password this scenes will be deleted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There shouldn't be a problem but this looks like an abuse of scene to me. You have too many unnecessary scenes.

Here is when you need to create or use a new scene:

**1**.Main Menu

This is the first scene that loads. By separating it with your game scene, you will increase loading time.

**2**.Game Levels

The levels in your game requires scene for each one. This makes loading them faster. You can also separate one scene into multiple ones if it's really a big scene. This also increases the speed of loading time.

---

You do not need scene for other things you have in your question. Those should be a **UI Panels**. You can create a panel by going to the *GameObject* ---> *UI* --> *Panel* menu. It's really easy to show/hide a panel.

For example, you have login and emergency panels:

```
public GameObject loginPanel;
public GameObject emergencyPanel;
```

to show the login panel, you disable or deactivate the emergency panel first then activate the login panel:

```
emergencyPanel.SetActive(false);
loginPanel.SetActive(true);
```

That's all you have to do.